# Como ocultar datos duplicados que se muestran en una tabla en php

Tags: php, html, mysql

** Me explico mejor sobre la imagen, lo que quiero es que solo se muestre "un proyecto por ID", cabe destacar que no quiero usar las instrucciones "DISTINCT, ORDER BY o TOP", debido a que ocupo los campos defectos_proyecto_estado.Estatus, defectos_proyecto_estado.Total para sacar el porcentaje de avance, (estos campos hacen que se repitan los resultados de salida), espero y me pueda ayudar [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] **

```
  <div class="container-fluid" id="cabecera">
  <table bgcolor = "#808000" align="center" class="table-responsive">
    <?php
//query utilizado para mostrar los resultados en una tabla
        $sql1 = 'SELECT DISTINCTROW proyecto.IDProyectoSpiraTest, proyecto.NombreProyecto, proyecto.Activo, complemento.Estado, defectos_proyecto_estado.Estatus, defectos_proyecto_estado.Total FROM complemento INNER JOIN defectos_proyecto_estado ON complemento.IDProyectoSpiraTestFK = defectos_proyecto_estado.IDProyectoSpiraTest INNER JOIN proyecto ON complemento.IDProyectoSpiraTestFK = proyecto.IDProyectoSpiraTest WHERE proyecto.Activo = 1 AND complemento.NombreProyecto = proyecto.NombreProyecto';
        if (isset($this->valor)) {
            $sql1 .= " AND proyecto.NombreProyecto LIKE '" . $this->valor . "%'";
        }
        //Limitamos el total de resultados por hoja
        $sql1 .= ' LIMIT ' . (($Pagination->get_page() - 1) * $Total_pagina) . ',' . $Total_pagina;
        $sql = $conexion->query($sql1);
        //devolvemos cada fila del resultado del query
        while ($row = $sql->fetch_object()) {
            ?>
  <td align="left">ID proyecto:<?php echo "$row->IDProyectoSpiraTest"; ?></td>
  <td align="left">Nombre:
  <a href="MostrarTab.php?NombreProyecto=<?php echo urlencode("$row->NombreProyecto"); ?>"><?php echo utf8_encode("$row->NombreProyecto"); ?></a></td>
  <td><?php echo str_replace(1, "Activo", "$row->Activo"); ?></td>
  <td align="left">
  <?php if ($row->Estado == 'Analisis y Diseño de Pruebas') {
                echo "<strong style='color:red'> $row->Estado</strong>";
            } else if ($row->Estado == 'Ejecucion de Pruebas') {
                echo "<strong style='color:#04B404'> $row->Estado</strong>";
            } else if ($row->Estado == 'En Espera de Desarrollo') {
                echo "<strong style='color:#DF7401'> $row->Estado</strong>";
            } else if ($row->Estado == 'En tramite') {
                echo "<strong style='color:blue'> $row->Estado</strong>";
            } else if ($row->Estado == 'Nueva Asignacion') {
                echo "<strong style='color:blue'> $row->Estado</strong>";
            } else if ($row->Estado == 'Suspendido') {
                echo "<strong style='color:#DF0101'> $row->Estado</strong>";
            } else if ($row->Estado == 'Cancelado') {
                echo "<strong style='color:#6E6E6E'> $row->Estado</strong>";
            } else if ($row->Estado == 'Pruebas Terminadas') {
                echo "<strong style='color:#000000'> $row->Estado</strong>";
            }
            $a = $row->Estatus;
            if ($a == 'Closed') {
                $FallasC += $row->Total;
            }
            $FallasD += $row->Total;
            echo $porcentaje = ($FallasC / $FallasD) * 100?>
</td>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="4">
        <div class="container">
          <h2>Progreso</h2>
          <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-10 col-lg-12">
            <div class="progress">
              <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="10" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:<?php echo $porcentaje ?>%">
              10%
              </div>
            </div>
           </div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <?php
}
        ?>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: No me termina de quedar claro lo que quieres conseguir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo  puedes resolver en el SQL o en PHP, personalmente se me hace más facil resolverlo en el query que en código pero vamos a ver:

```
$proyecto = [];
...
...
while ($row = $sql->fetch_object()) {
 if(!in_array($row->IDProyectoSpiraTest, $proyecto)){
   ... //aquí estás imprimiendo los datos del proyecto que se imprimen una sola vez.
   $proyecto[] = $row->IDProyectoSpiraTest;
 } else {
   ... //aquí se imprimen los datos que se repiten.
 }
}
```

Primero creamos un array para guardar los proyectos, luego en cada registro del SQL revisamos si existe este proyecto e imprimimos la información que queremos, cuando no existe entonces agregamos el proyecto al array para que en el proximo registro SQL ya exista.

En el Query puedes hacer operaciones aritméticas o funciones de ventana para resolver tu problema. Mi recomendación es que investigues un poco sobre eso en lugar de modificar tu código PHP que ya tiene pinta bastante compleja.

Comment: Gracias por la información Solrac, pero tenias razon fue mas fácil solucionarlo por medio del Query